# RTU card of SCADA systems

Tags: microcontroller, control, control-system, smart-card

In most of electrical [SCADA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCADA) systems, [RTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Terminal_Unit) (Remote Terminal Unit) panels are very common in power transmission & distribution companies. There are several cards inside each RTU panel, some are binary input/output cards and the others are analogue input/output. I would like to ask about the function of these cards? These are some images of that cards:
[image]
[image]
[image]

***Edit:*** This is the data sheet of [23BE23](http://www05.abb.com/global/scot/scot258.nsf/veritydisplay/a384c03eca766ad6c1257847004e6c73/$file/E560_23BE23_DS.pdf) card not 23BE21,but I guess it is for same purpose.

Comment: Don't assume that everybody knows what you're talking about when you use uncommon abbreviations. Explain the context, and be more precise about your question; it's too vague the way it is now.

Comment: @Federico Russo : I hope it is better now.

Comment: If you post the chip numbers, and links to their data sheets we could offer a better guess as to the card function.

Comment: @SteveR : Thanks for your response, see the new edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not offer very much information, however this is the basics. An RTU receives and transmits information to and from a master control station. Typically that being a central control station, such as a control office in a power utility. The satellite remotes can be electrical substations, for instance, which will have their switching remotely controlled. These satellite stations will report the position of switching and can also report real time data such as voltage or current readings. The "card type" RTU is commonly being replaced by [PLC's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) which usually use [Ladder logic](http://www.opamp-electronics.com/tutorials/digital_theory_ch_006.htm) so as the functions can easily be reprogrammed.

EDIT:
You should be able to get some clues as to the cards function by looking up the chip numbers. The older systems did not have analog capabilities, not sure about this one.

How many pins are on the header? Could possibly be an  [SBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-board_computer) with format  [PC-104](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/104) compatibility?